# PHP add <div "style="clear"> </div> in a loop after every 4 records

Tags: php, html, css

To style a page correctly I need to add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after every 4 records in a loop.

Currently every records outputted into a php file and displayed in a `<div>` like I have below.

```
<div>content</div>
```

On every 4th record I would like to add a clear `<div>` like this:

```
<div>content</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want a loop for automatically creating those divs?

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can upgrade it.

Comment: @andreas I'm just learning php. So I might have the terminology wrong. Basically my script pulls records from a table that has about 5 fields. Then it places them into a set of div tags. There are several divs with echo statements within the main div container. I would have put them up, but I thought it would be too much stuff for the question. I can put them up if you would like me to?

Comment: @AniruddhaSarkar There are so many lines and divs, do you want to see it all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a modulos

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    echo '<div>'.$row.'</div>';
    if (($i++ % 4) == 0) echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
}
```

You should not use `mysql` as it is deprecated. Instead, use `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Comment: Since you're incrementing `$i` *after* checking its value, your `if` should be `if($i%4==3)`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Right, helped me think of a better way to do the whole thing (and remove half of the `if` conditional)

Comment: Its not working, I was trying to mess with it some to see if I could get it. It is giving this `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/shopping/public_html/retailers.php on line 257` Line 257 is the 2nd line of your code

Comment: @sjagr assumed that you defined $items as an array like in my example above.

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia you can't just copy and paste my code verbatim and expect it to work. I had no idea what you had stored your results in so I assumed a variable name of `$items` (maybe you should have posted your own code so we could see what you tried so far.) You could also use `while ($item = mysqli_fetch_row())` or something like that in lieu of the `foreach` function.

Comment: Sorry Sjagr, I am new to php... Thanks for your help though. I know this is not what a fiddle is for, but just so you can see the code, I put the whole loop in the html. I thought putting all this code was overkill for the question, people have told me not do that before. http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/jE7Gu/2/

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia posting some code is still very helpful though. Now here's some problems: 1) Where have you defined `$cc`? 2) Why are you using `$i % 4 == 0` for even/odd? 3) Where have you defined `$i`? 4) I don't see any full implementation of the answer I gave you, so where are you putting it exactly?

Comment: `$cc = 0` and `$i = 0` And I am not going to use the odd/even output anymore, it was to change the background color, but I'm not going to use it anymore, so I can get rid of that. Regarding your implementation of your answer, I tried it after the array to see if it would work. But I really want to place it at the bottom before the loop close.

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia I've modified my original answer to adapt to your code. Use `$i = 1` **not** `$i = 1`. Replace `echo '<div>'.$row.'</div>';` with the content you're using. Try to understand what my code does so you know how you should plug it into your own solution.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to look it over now. I'm slow, but I just voted up  a few of your previous answers to give you some points for all the time you put in. thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia no problem - if you're still having trouble, shoot me a message and show me how far you've gotten

Comment: Thanks, going to be a little slow going because its Christmas eve here and family are coming :)

Comment: Actually I do have 1 question. Are you suggesting I update the array or add another one?

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia implement my answer in your existing `while` function. You already have the `while` row done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43856/discussion-between-michael-falciglia-and-sjagr)

Comment: Not sure how it notifies you of the chat, so I figured I would add this here. It worked, except it is outputting `<div>Array</div>' at the bottom of the each of the first 3, then on every 4th it adds the `<div style="clear:both">`

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to you loop body ought to do the trick

```
if ($i != 0 && $i % 4 == 0) 
  //Output clear div here
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this using your answer `<?php if ($i != 0 && $i % 4 == 0) echo "clear"; else echo "none"; ?>` But it echoed `none` for every result.

Comment: Maybe I put it in the wrong place. I put it the first line of my loop after my array like this  `<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $cc++;?> <?php if ($i != 0 && $i % 4 == 0) echo "clear"; else echo "none"; ?>`

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia You are not incrementing $i in that code. That's why it is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use CSS as well, for example like this:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .normaldiv {
        /* other stuff here */
    }
    .cleardiv {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

**PHP**

```
$array = array(
    'data1',
    'data2',
    'data3',
    ...
    'datan'
);

$html = '';

foreach ($array as $i => $data) {
    // Add class "normaldiv" or "normaldiv cleardiv"
    $html .= '<div class="normaldiv' . ( $i%4 == 3 ? ' cleardiv' : '' ) . '">' . $data . '</div>';
}

// Do anything with your html string
echo $html;
```

Maybe you need to adjust it to your needs (for example using an if clause within the foreach, if you want to make an empty div without css class "normaldiv").

Comment: Hi I am novice at best. This is my array `<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $cc++;?>` How do I add your suggestion into the array or would that be a new array?